# Running a process within my Python code

Tags: python

I have a Python code, and within it, it runs a little program using *os*:

```
os.system('commands to run program')
```

This all works fine, but at the end of the internal program, it requires that I type 'Y' before the rest of my Python program will continue.

I thought that I could take care of this by again using something like:

```
os.system('Y')
```

But my program still gets stuck at the input request. After I manually type 'Y', then my Python code continues again NOW types 'Y'.

I'm clearly doing something wrong. Could you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

For example:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('commands to run program', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(input='Y')
p.wait()
```

etc.